# Can't remove Opera and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opera

I'm that kind of user who likes to have different browsers, media players, etc. Today I just wanted to try out Opera and Google Chrome, but I don't want to use them anymore so I thought that I remove them. The problem is I can't find them in Ubuntu Software Center or when I use 'remove opera' in terminal it doesn't work.
Can you tell me how to remove them properly?

Comment: What is the output of your remove command (and what command did you use exactly)?

Comment: Well I've downloaded the opera.deb file and installed it via USC. But now when I type opera in USC's search...nothing. So I tried apt-get remove opera/opera-stable, but still nothing. I'm almost sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out the proper way.

Comment: Have a look here: [How to install applications when you're a Windows user](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) and upvote it when it helped...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a Terminal and put in:

```
sudo apt-get remove opera-stable
```

to remove opera and

```
 sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

to remove chrome

Answer (score 3):

In Software Center go to Installed and from right side of the **Installed** click on the **down arrow** button and select **Unknown** - You will see Opera and Chrome there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have installed these two pieces of software successfully?

Try this:

```
dpkg -s opera-stable google-chrome-stable
```

If you see `dpkg-query: package 'nlll' is not installed and no information is available` that means you didn't install that.

Also, if you install that, you will see lots of files.

Answer (score 2):

Use purge to delete the configurations as well

example:

```
sudo apt-get purge opera-stable
```

Comment: This would be better either as a complete answer (i.e., an answer that does not depend on reading other answers) or as a comment

Comment: I agree completely! I would have loved to have added it as a comment to the post it's adding to. Except Askubuntu's permissions are such that a new user gains ability to provide "answers" prior to being able to add comments. I can comment only on my own posts at this time.

Comment: okay than.
No problem =P

Answer (score 1):

After a long searching process, I used `sudo snap remove opera-beta` command and it is working. I forget that i installed `opera-beta` from snap.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this command : `sudo snap remove opera`